# Avoid nested Wsdl's in WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, xsd, wsdl

I'm currently searching for a way to get a single Wsdl file **with multiple Xsd references** for my .NET 4.5 WCF Service.
I know that I can use ?singleWsdl Parameter to get a single Wsdl **containing all Xsd's included in my Wsdl**. But I need these seperate Xsd's.

**current scenario:**

```
MyService.svc?wsdl
MyService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0
MyService.svc?wsdl=wsdl1
...
MyService.svc?xsd=xsd0
MyService.svc?xsd=xsd1
...
```

**wanted scenario:**

```
MyService.svc?wsdl
MyService.svc?xsd=xsd0
MyService.svc?xsd=xsd1
...
```

**scenario using ?singleWsdl**

```
MyService.svc?singleWsdl
[no more]
```

Any way to do this by configuring WCF? Or any free tool to do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by myself.
I used different namespaces for the service contracts on the one hand and for the service behaviors on the other. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the

```
IWsdlExportExtension
```

interface which allows you to modify the wsdl exposed by your service.

And here is [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/10/06/wcf-extensibility-wsdl-export-extension.aspx) with an example.